# Can't convert data retrieved from datasets to a model type ienumerables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I always get the error-- cannot convert to 'MvcMusicStore.Models.MusicStore.GenreDataTable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' 
I am pasting my code below
the controller:

```
using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using MvcMusicStore.Models;

  namespace MvcMusicStore.Controllers
  {
  public class StoreController : Controller
  {    

    // GET: /Store/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         MvcMusicStore.Models.MusicStoreTableAdapters.GenreTableAdapter ta= new Models.MusicStoreTableAdapters.GenreTableAdapter();
         var genres = ta.GetData().AsEnumerable();
         return View(genres);
    }
```

my model:

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
public partial class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

}

and at last the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h3>Browse Genres</h3>
<p>
Select from @Model.Count()
genres:
</p>
<ul>
@foreach (var genre in Model)
{
       <li>@Html.ActionLink(genre.Name,
"Browse", new { genre = genre.Name })</li>

}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ta.GetData()` is not returning an object that can be cast into an `IEnumerable<Genre>`. Based on the error message it seems that `ta.GetData()` is returning a `GenreDataTable` object. If that is correct, I see a couple of things:

1. In the Razor view, the model is looking for a IEnumerable of `Genre` objects not a `GenreDataTable` object.
2. If your `GenreDataTable` object is already a collection, then have that as the return model instead of the IEnumerable.
3. If `GenreDataTable` is not a collection of `Genre` objects, then you've got to either update the required model in the Razor view, or update the controller code to create the required type to match the model.

Comment: Thank you @Jwatts1980. I got it solved myself. I made a Genre Object and and a list of Genre type. I added the values retrieved from ta.GetData to the list and returned the list to the view and it worked.

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
          
            List<Genre> results = new List<Genre>();
             MvcMusicStore.Models.MusicStoreTableAdapters.GenreTableAdapter ta= new Models.MusicStoreTableAdapters.GenreTableAdapter();
         var    genres = ta.GetData().ToList();
         foreach (var v in genres)
         {
             Genre genre = new Genre();
             genre.GenreId=v.GenreID;
             genre.Name = v.Name;
             genre.Description = v.Details;
             results.Add(genre);
         }
             return View(results);
        }

Comment: Alternatively, you can use LINQ to do it this way also: `var genres = ta.GetData().Select(v => new Genre() { GenreId = v.GenreID, Name = v.Name, Description = v.Details }).ToList();`